# Create drawable with colored background and centered icon

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to create a drawable painted by color with centered icon. I tried to create layer-list but it scales icon to match drawable size:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorImageHolder"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/no_photo" android:gravity="center">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This is a real device picture:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Is there any way to disable icon scaling ?

UPDATE: My `ImageView` has `scaleType="centerCrop"` and I think this is a root of problem :( I tried to place no_photo drawable as background but it scales again.

Comment: have you uploaded all types of image(hdpi ldpi mdpi xdpi?

Comment: Yes. Icon contain all needed dimensions

Comment: use `<bitmap>` tag with a `android:gravity` inside the second `<item>`

Comment: Yes. This is a solution. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @AlexandrShutko if pskink don't like to post the answer, you can post your answer, or update your question with the answer, it will help other person

Comment: @Phan Văn Linh, lets wait a little for pskink and i'll add it as answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inside your second `<item>` tag add the following `<bitmap>` tag so it reads:

```
<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/no_photo" android:gravity="center" />
</item>
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorImageHolder"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/no_photo"
          android:bottom="20dp"
          android:left="20dp"
          android:right="20dp"
          android:top="20dp"
    >
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Note: This solution only work with square or oval view, not rectangle

Comment: @AlexandrShutko I suggest, you should use the solution by pskink. with my solution, you can only apply it for square view, or oval view

Comment: @AlexandrShutko use <bitmap> tag with a android:gravity inside the second <item>

Answer (score 0):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="44dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <size
            android:width="44dp"
            android:height="44dp" />

    </shape>


</item>

<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_menu" android:gravity="center"/>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).